# Access to a X509 certificate with private key

Tags: c#, windows, security, x509certificate

I was just wondering about the following scenario: I have a certificate containing a private key in my Windows certificate store and would like to use it for signing stuff. Is it possible to let Windows do this, so that I do not need to make the private key accessible (like in TPM)? In case I really must make the private key accessible, how can I protect it from being accessed by other (potentially malicious) applications? Having a separate user account?

Thanks

Comment: certificates never containing a private key. private key - always external. if private key not accessible in windows - you can not use it here.

Comment: Certificates can contain private keys - *.pfx. And my question is related to how to prevent other apps from accessing the key since I don't want it to be "stolen"

Comment: pfx - this is not certificate but container which containing certificate and private key - if be exactly. if one code can access private key, some another code also can access it

Comment: Exactly what I mean, so how to prevent it? Different user account with it Current User\My store?

Comment: Or can windows create a signature based on the private key internally?

Comment: `Or can windows create a signature based on the private key internally?` - ?? only one solution - be sure that only you access windows where private key stored and no malicious applications. if you assume that some malicious applications can be in your windows - nothing prevent from potential access